# Excel VBA - Select Case ends select after finding one case true and doesn't complete other cases

Tags: vba, excel

I created a loop that would check the length of columns and column types.  But once it finds a case to be true it ends the select instead of going to the next case (column) where there could be an additional error.

'(6.1) Create loop to check for format and length errors
           xRowCount = 1
           xFormatErrorCount = 0

```
       For i = 0 To xNumOfRows - 1

       xColA = Cells(xRowCount, 1).Value
       xColB = Cells(xRowCount, 2).Value
       xColC = Cells(xRowCount, 3).Value
       xColD = Cells(xRowCount, 4).Value
       xColE = Cells(xRowCount, 5).Value
       xColF = Cells(xRowCount, 6).Value
       xColG = Cells(xRowCount, 7).Value
       xColH = Cells(xRowCount, 8).Value
       xColI = Cells(xRowCount, 9).Value
       xColJ = Cells(xRowCount, 10).Value
       xColK = Cells(xRowCount, 11).Value
       xColL = Cells(xRowCount, 12).Value
       xColM = Cells(xRowCount, 13).Value

       Select Case True

        Case Len(xColA) > 2 'Check if length is greater than 2
         Cells(xRowCount, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1

        Case Len(xColB) > 5 'Check if length is greater than 5
         Cells(xRowCount, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1

        Case Len(xColC) > 5, Cells(xRowCount, 3).NumberFormat <> "0" 'Check if length is greater than 5 and format is number
         Cells(xRowCount, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1

        Case Len(xColD) > 18, Cells(xRowCount, 4).NumberFormat <> "0"  'Check if length is greater than 18 and format is number
         Cells(xRowCount, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1

        Case Len(xColE) > 11, Cells(xRowCount, 5).NumberFormat <> "0"  'Check if length is greater than 11 and format is number
         Cells(xRowCount, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1

        Case Cells(xRowCount, 6).NumberFormat <> "0"  'Check if format is number
         Cells(xRowCount, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1

        Case Cells(xRowCount, 7).NumberFormat <> "0"  'Check if #
         Cells(xRowCount, 7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1

        Case Cells(xRowCount, 8).NumberFormat <> "0"  'Check if #
        Cells(xRowCount, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1

        Case Cells(xRowCount, 9).NumberFormat <> "0"  'Check if #
         Cells(xRowCount, 9).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1

        Case Cells(xRowCount, 10).NumberFormat <> "0.00"  'Check if # 
         Cells(xRowCount, 10).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1

        Case Len(xColK) > 1 'Check if length is greater than 1
         Cells(xRowCount, 11).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1

        Case Len(xColL) > 1  'Check if length is greater than 1
         Cells(xRowCount, 12).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1

        Case Len(xColM) > 1  'Check if length is greater than 1
         Cells(xRowCount, 13).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1


       End Select
        xRowCount = xRowCount + 1
```

Next

Comment: That's how `Select` statements work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278665.aspx

Comment: Yes, `Case` does not fall-through.

Comment: How could I modify it for what I need it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as though you don't want `Select Case`, which is designed to behave the way you describe, at all but rather a series of separate If statements:

```
Dim n                           As Long

If Len(xColA) > 2 Then    'Check if length is greater than 2
    Cells(xRowCount, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1
End If
If Len(xColB) > 5 Then    'Check if length is greater than 5
    Cells(xRowCount, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1
End If
If Len(xColC) > 5 Or Cells(xRowCount, 3).NumberFormat <> "0" Then    'Check if length is greater than 5 and format is number
    Cells(xRowCount, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1
End If
If Len(xColD) > 18 Or Cells(xRowCount, 4).NumberFormat <> "0" Then  'Check if length is greater than 18 and format is number
    Cells(xRowCount, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1
End If
If Len(xColE) > 11 Or Cells(xRowCount, 5).NumberFormat <> "0" Then  'Check if length is greater than 11 and format is number
    Cells(xRowCount, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1
End If
For n = 6 To 9
    If Cells(xRowCount, n).NumberFormat <> "0" Then    'Check if format is number
        Cells(xRowCount, n).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1
    End If
Next n
If Cells(xRowCount, 10).NumberFormat <> "0.00" Then    'Check if #
    Cells(xRowCount, 10).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1
End If
If Len(xColK) > 1 Then    'Check if length is greater than 1
    Cells(xRowCount, 11).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1
End If
If Len(xColL) > 1 Then    'Check if length is greater than 1
    Cells(xRowCount, 12).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1
End If
If Len(xColM) > 1 Then  'Check if length is greater than 1
    Cells(xRowCount, 13).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    xFormatErrorCount = xFormatErrorCount + 1
End If
```

I think you could probably streamline this more using arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This is how VB select case works.

If you want to have multiple cases that execute the same block, you put them in the same case and delimit them with commas, like this:

```
Public Sub TestX(ByVal x As Long)


    Select Case x
        Case 1, 2
            Debug.Print "x is One or Two"
        Case 3
            Debug.Print "x is Three"
        Case Else
            Debug.Print ; "is something else"
    End Select


End Sub
```